# Laravel include without inheriting variables from parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to

`@include('something', [])`

without variables from parent. Is that possible?

> Even though the included view will inherit all data available in the parent view, you may also pass an array of additional data that should be made available to the included view

from
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews

The problem with components is that you have to do sort of a split. E.g. say you have a page in

`resources/views/mything/guest/buyer/layout/mysubview.blade.php`

now I want to mark that something is related to this view, by creating an include folder say

`resources/views/mything/guest/buyer/layout/includes/myspecialtableheader.blade.php`

if I put it into a component, that is *really* far away from the folder where it is being used.

is there a different solution to having includes not having access to variables? or maybe something entirely different. Components which I can put wherever maybe. Maybe one can do something with `@component` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least impossible at time of writting (2022).

Blade does **not** even provide a check, like:

```
@if(View::hasOwn('myVariable'))
    Do something ...
@endif
```

> Which would distinguish passed variables from existing ones (but it's sudo-code, and `hasOwn`-method does not exist).
>
> Also, the only workaround I can think of is prefixing, like:
>
> ```
> @include('layouts.myLayoutAlpha', [
>    'myLayoutAlpha_myVariable' => 'some value',
> ])
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a subview as component with local scope you can do it like this:

```
@component('mything.guest.buyer.layout.includes.myspecialtableheader',
['lovalVar1'=>$var1, 'lovalVar2'=>$var2, ])
@endcomponent
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Just be aware that when using this, you may not use other "out of the box" variables that may come inside a loop and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have a trick that i use in this case. The comments are enough to understand.

```
@php
    $data['var'] = 'Set by view or inherited from previous assignements';
@endphp

{{-- Inheriting from previously set data --}}
@include('Part')

{{-- Passing data --}}
@include('Part', [
    'data' => [
        "var" => "Set by inlcude"
    ],
])

{{-- Reset previously set data (Always pass the array to subview even empty) --}}
@include('Part', ['data' => []])
```

on the Part:

```
<p>{{$data["var"] ?? 'No var set'}}</p>
```